# Segmentation fault with sizeof() on a small array ( C )

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm having this weird issue. I've looked on other Stack Overflow posts, but they're dealing with large arrays that wouldn't affect anything with my code. They've recommended `malloc()` but it would be useless on something as small as this.

I'm practicing with C, and a simple thing like this:

```c
int main()
{
    char* things[] = {"test1\n", "test2\n", "test3\n"};

    for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(things) - 1; i++)
    {
        printf(things[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Gives a segmentation fault. It actually does end up printing test1, test2, test3, though. After it's done with that it gives a segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you aware of the value of `sizeof(things)`? It will surprise you and explain almost completly.

Comment: sizeof is the total size in bytes of things, which is  likely 3*8 or 24.

Comment: When you found that out try `sizeof(things)/sizeof(things[0])`.

Comment: Oh. Well I'm an idiot lol

Comment: Anybody has a dupe? Or shall I turn my two comments into an answer? Or shall we close as thinko?

Comment: Turn it into an answer, it worked.

Comment: Maybe  https://stackoverflow.com/q/37538/1216776

Comment: Not bad. Though I think contrasting against the (possible) expectation of number of characters in all strings is worth keeping my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual value of `sizeof(things)` will surprise you. Find it out.
As user stark explains:

> sizeof is the total size in bytes of things, which is likely 3*8 or 24.

To be more explicit, it it not the number of characters in your quasi-strings, it is the size of pointers in your environment times 3.

So the solution is to divide the total by the size of one:

`sizeof(things)/sizeof(things[0])`.